# Apply function to return data based on next rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, apply

Hello guys I have a dataframe `ready_df` that looks like this:

| timestamp | Latitude_1 | Longtitude_1 | Name | Latitude_2 | Longtitude_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:00.100 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 12.3456 | 12.3456 |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:00.300 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 12.3456 | 12.3456 |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:00.500 | 12.3456 | 12.3456 | Billy | NaN | NaN |

I have to fill column `Name` with values for which `Latitude_2    Longtitude_2` == `Latitude_1    Longtitude_1`
I created a function which i called `filler()`, here is the code of the function:

```
def filler(Nan_lon, Full_lon, Nan_lat, Full_lat, Designated_col):
    if ready_df[Nan_lon] == ready_df[Full_lon].iloc[1] and ready_df[Nan_lan] == ready_df[Full_lan].iloc[1]:
        return ready_df[Designated_col].iloc[1]
    elif ready_df[Nan_lon] == ready_df[Full_lon].iloc[2] and ready_df[Nan_lan] == ready_df[Full_lan].iloc[2]:
        return ready_df[Designated_col].iloc[2]
    elif ready_df[Nan_lon] == ready_df[Full_lon].iloc[3] and ready_df[Nan_lan] == ready_df[Full_lan].iloc[3]:
        return ready_df[Designated_col].iloc[3]
    else:
        return np.NaN
```

I want to check maximum 3 rows ahead of current row if 2 rows before are `nan` else i want to return `nan`. However when i use it to fill the column like this:

```
ready_df['NAME'] = ready_df.apply(lambda x: filler(Nan_lon=x.Longtitude_2, Full_lon=x.Longtitude_1,
                                                           Nan_lat=x.Latitude_2, Full_lat=x.Latitude_1,
                                                           Designated_col=ready_df['NAME']))
```

I get an error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Longitude'`

Whole idea is to fill column `Name` - then i planned to change the function for each column so I have each NaN filled with correct values. Dataframe has 130k rows. Could you please explain why is my function not working and suggest any improvements, thanks :)

EDIT:

```
| timestamp | Latitude_1 | Longtitude_1 | Name | Latitude_2 | Longtitude_2 |
| --------- | ---------- | ------------ | ---- | ---------- | ------------ |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:00.100 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 12.3456 | 12.3456 |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:00.300 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 12.3456 | 12.3456 |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:00.500 | 12.3456 | 12.3456 | Billy | NaN | NaN |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:00.700 | 21.345| 21.345| John| NaN | NaN |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:00.900 | 21.345| 21.345| John| NaN | NaN |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:01.100 | 12.3456 | 12.3456 | Billy | NaN | NaN |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:01.300 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 21.345| 21.345|
| 2021-03-03 08:00:01.500 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 21.345| 21.345|
| 2021-03-03 08:00:01.700 | 12.3456 | 12.3456 | Billy | NaN | NaN |
```

Expected output:

| timestamp | Latitude_1 | Longtitude_1 | Name | Latitude_2 | Longtitude_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:00.100 | 12.3456 | 12.3456 | Billy | 12.3456 | 12.3456 |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:00.300 | 12.3456 | 12.3456 | Billy | 12.3456 | 12.3456 |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:00.500 | 12.3456 | 12.3456 | Billy | 12.3456 | 12.3456 |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:00.700 | 21.345 | 21.345 | John | 21.345 | 21.345 |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:00.900 | 21.345 | 21.345 | John | 21.345 | 21.345 |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:01.100 | 12.3456 | 12.3456 | Billy | 12.3456 | 12.3456 |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:01.300 | 21.345 | 21.345 | John | 21.345 | 21.345 |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:01.500 | 21.345 | 21.345 | John | 21.345 | 21.345 |
| 2021-03-03 08:00:01.700 | 12.3456 | 12.3456 | Billy | 12.3456 | 12.3456 |

Answer (score 0):

Take this with a grain of salt but you might have to fundamentally reconsider how you are you implementing apply() here. And because I don't ultimately know what your result should be, some of this can be out of context.

1. using apply like this only sends one row of data, but you want to test against three; then repeat each row for the length of the dataframe. You may want to consider using some sort of slice instead where you can iterate through the dataframe taking three rows at a time
2. However, your error on x.Longtitude_2 is because that syntax thinks there an attribute of x, so using x['Longitutde_2'] clears that error, but then you get a keyword error, which is cleared by using argument axis=1, which leads to another error 'NAME' not being defined. This argument Designated_col=ready_df['NAME'] shouldn't be in in the lambda or the functions argument list as you are trying to create it by ready_df['NAME'] = ready_df....
3. Beyond that you are passing Nan_lon=x.Longtitude_2 which is a value to your function and ready_df[Nan_lon] which throws key error because it's looking for ready_df['12.3456'] where I think you want ready_df['Longtitude_2']
4. Didn't get past this point....

If you can post a few more lines of ready_df AND your expected output dataframe, you may get better advice.

Comment: Hi Jonathan I just edited the question with all the details like you asked, now I know that apply() is definetly not the way for this sort of stuff, thank you for that. Do you have any suggestions after seeing edited question?